# why users and sessions numbers are different when I use only "sourceMedium" or "sourceMedium" + "campaign" dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics

When I have a custom report with the same date range, same view and same segment, I am getting different figures on users and sessions with ~7% discrepancy.

See below:

A. Using sourceMedium only:

[image: Google Analytics Report]

B. Using sourceMedium + campaign:

[image: same segment, same date range, one extra dimension]

Sampling is excluded, as we're sitting at GA360 suite + the same picture repeats when I pull numbers via API or unsampled report. Please help me to understand the reason for such huge discrepancies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sentence "*Sampling is excluded, as we're sitting at GA360 suite*" is not right.

Sampling, although with a much higher limit, also exists for G360 (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en). I don't know if it is your case however considering that you wrote that you used a segment it can be probable.

In your case, I don't see why the data is returned to you differently, unless I think about sampling so:

- try to export an **unsampled report** (functionality available only in G360) for both and then make the comparison

[image]

Comment: Hey Michele, thanks for your reply! I've checked the data using both API extraction and via unsampled report, and still getting different total numbers :(